# Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am facing problems in invoking a method present in a web service. The wsdl was created using AXIS.

When I try to invoke it using my java code, I am getting null values from the service response.

I am getting the warning message getting printed in my console:

> Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

While trying to solve this, I added activation.jar and mail.jar in my workspace build path, restarted the server.

**EDIT:**

Right Click on the WSDL ==> Generate CLient

Then I got a proxy class, using it I wrote this to invoke the service method:

```
public class CallingWebService1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebService1Proxy proxy1 = new WebService1Proxy();
    proxy1.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8045/WebService1/services/WebService1");

    EmployeeDetails details = proxy1.getDetails();
    System.out.println("Employee Id: " + details.getEmpId());
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + details.getEmpName());
    System.out.println("Dept Id: " + details.getDeptId());
    System.out.println("Dept Name" + details.getDeptName());
    System.out.println("Age: " + details.getAge());
}
```

But still the problem persists :(

**Further Info:**

The getDetails() method is performing a DB operation fetching some records from the Oracle DB. For performing the DB operation, class12.jar is used. Does it have something to do with invoking the service method the way I am doing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In order to fix the javax.activation.DataHandler issue you must add the [JavaBeans Activation Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html) activation.jar in your classpath.

In order to fix the javax.mail.internet.mimeMultipart issue you must add the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) mail.jar in your classpath.

The warning messages printed in your console shows that the above jars are not in the classpath.

Comment: I did it in my 1st attempt before posting this in the forum.please read the bottom part of my question.

Comment: Were the warnings disappeared after including the jars in the classpath?

Comment: NO, adding the jars did not removed the warnings. I have edited the original post to show how i am trying to invoke the web service method. Please suggest.

Comment: The JavaBeans activation framework is included in Java SE (since Java 6, maybe even since Java 5; not sure).

Comment: the jars are in my classpath........i mentioned this in my initial question several times....i checked this even before posting this question.

Comment: @user182944, a little late to the party, but the message indicates that _at least one_ of the jars mentioned in the answer is missing, but not necessarily both.  As activation is part of Java SE now, it is most likely that javax.mail is missing...

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis - Does not work anymore even after adding activation.jar to the build path. Is it okay if I ignore the warning ?

Answer (score 27):

Only **one jar (mail.jar) is enough** to fix this problem. This jar should present in your class path.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, wsdl is still in use:( You can solve this warn via adding dependencies below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```