# An error associated with mail.jar occurs although my application has no email sending included

Tags: java, email, lib

I have "inherited" a Java programme which accesses APIs of Polarion and Mantis. The application had mail.jar in its lib folder which I removed because sending emails is not a part of the application.

However, since I removed this library, the first line in the Eclipse console is...

```
[WARN] JavaUtils - Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Can you explain me why this warning occurs although my application has nothing to do with emails? The warning has no impact on my application, it runs smoothly.

This is the list of libraries which is in the lib folder of my application, they are all included in the properties of my project apart from the mail.jar.

axis-1.4.jar

commons-codec-1.4.jar

commons-discovery-0.2.jar

commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

commons-logging-1.0.4.jar

jaxrpc.jar

junit.jar

logback-classic-1.0.11.jar

logback-core-1.0.11.jar

mail.jar

mantis-axis-soap-client-1.2.19.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

wsclient.jar

wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

Please do not write comments like "But do YOU really know that there is NO email sending in the code?" Yes, I know this because I know the code off the cuff. 
Please do not mark this is as a duplicate of [Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227035/unable-to-find-required-classes-javax-activation-datahandler-and-javax-mail-int) because it simply isn't. I want to get rid of this mail.jar library, not including it for supressing a warning.

Comment: The text in my thread says that mail.jar is not included. It is not in the classpath nor buildpath. I deleted the library now completely but the warning still occurs.

Comment: Also done already, no change.

Comment: @Santosh Did you even rid the thread text? I do NOT want to send emails with my application, I want to know how I can get rid of these warnings without the need of including this mail.jar library.

Comment: Since the message comes from JavaUtils which is apache axis. Can you check if axis has dependency on mail.jar?